# Change the indexing name for multidimensional array using array_map

Tags: php

I have array like the following

```
[ 'a' => 'b' , 
  'd' => 'c' , 
  'e' => [
  'f' => 'g'

]]
```

I want to use array_map to changes the index for this array like the following

```
[ '1' => 'b' , 
  '2' => 'c' , 
  '3' => [
  '4' => 'g'
]]
```

But array_map don't work with multidimensional array, and through error, how can i solve that ?

Comment: Is array_values() what you're looking for, or do the indexes need to start with 1?

Comment: note that `array_map` does work for multidimensional arrays, do you mean that it doesn't work with associative arrays?

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array('a' => 'b' , 
  'd' => 'c' , 
  'e' => '[',
  'f' => 'g');

$array1 = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array1[] = $value;
}

print_r($array1);
```

Comment: or if you like to start unset $array1[0]:

$array1[] = 'test';
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
 $array1[] = $value;
}
unset($array1[0]);